# How to allow user's custom shader for an openGL software

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, opentk

In softwares like Unity or Unreal, for example, how do they allow users to add their own custom shaders to an object?
Is this custom shader just a normal fragment shader or is it another kind of shader? And if it is just a fragment shader, how do they deal with the lights?

I'm not gonna post the code here because it's big and would pollute the page, but I'm starting to learn through here: https://github.com/opentk/LearnOpenTK/blob/master/Chapter2/6-MultipleLights/Shaders/lighting.frag (it's a series of tutorials, this is the shader from the last one), and they say we should put the light types in functions, inside the fragment shader, to calculate the colors of each fragment.

For example, this function to calculate a directional light, extracted from the code I sent above:

```
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
    //diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    //specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    //combine results
    vec3 ambient  = light.ambient  * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse  = light.diffuse  * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords));
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

But I've never seen people adding lights in their shaders in Unity for example, people just add textures and mess with colors, unless they really want to specifically mess with the lights.

Is there a way of making just one fragment shader that will compute all the types of light, and the user could then apply another shader, just for the object material, on top of that?

If you don't know how to answer but have some good reading material, or place where I could learn more about openGL and GLSL it would be of great value as well.

Comment: Shaders are just text, so you can do pretty much anything. Either take input from the user and process it in some way or just pass it directly to the GPU as it is.

Comment: You are basically asking to explain lighting in GLSL, which is unreasonable to answer here. It seems that you have very little experience with GLSL in general. I suggest you try some basic tutorials ([learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com) is a good place to start), after which you should have a better idea on how to write something like in your code example. Specifically, your question is answered [here](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting), but I strongly encourage you to read every prior lesson.

Comment: Game engines will use a large number of shader variations, often machine-generated, to cover different cases. If you can make a shader for a single light, then it's not hard to make versions of it for two lights, three lights, etc. The same goes for other material properties.

Comment: @Sedfer this is the exact same tutorial I followed, you didn't understood my question, and the link you sent doesn't answer it. But thank you for the link tho.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I thought about this before, but I was trying to know if there is a better/easier way of doing it. I think I could add the lighting functions to the user's shader and multiply it with the final color value of the fragment. I don't know if the way I'm thinking of doing it is the correct way though.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the source code of an open-source game engine to see what it does?

Comment: @Andrea good idea, I'll look into Godot's, I don't know if they use openGL but it will be a good start, but first I need to finish these tutorials, it was just a question that popped up when I was reading. The bad thing about studying online is that when we have questions we don't have a teacher to answer. But thank you for the idea, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to structure shader files, each with different pros and cons.

- ***As individual programs***. You make each file it's own shader program. Simple to add new programs, and would allow your users to just write a program in GLSL, HLSL, or an engines custom shader language. You will have to provide some way for the user to express what kind of data the program expects, unless you query it from the engine, but it might get complicated to make something that's generic enough.
- ***Über Shader!*** Put all desired functionality in one shader and let the behavior be controlled by control flow or preprocessor macros, such as `#ifdef`. So the user would just have to write the main function (which the application adds to the rest of the shader). This allows you to let the user use all the predefined variables and functions. The obvious downside is that it could be big and hard to handle and small changes might break many shaders.
- **Micro Shaders.** Each program contains a small, common functionality, and the application concatenate them all to a functioning shader. The user just write the main function and tells the program which functionality to add. The problem is that it's easy to get conflicts in names unless you're careful and is harder to implement than the *über shader*.
- **Effect files.** Provided by [Microsoft’s effect framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3d11-graphics-programming-guide-effects) or [NVIDIA’s CgFX framework](https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit) (deprecated).
- **Abstract Shade Trees.** Don't actually know what this is, but it's [suppose to be a solution](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/48546957_Abstract_Shade_Trees).

You can also combine some of these techniques or try to invent your own solution based on your needs. [Here's](https://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/research/publications/2007/bauchinger-2007-mre/bauchinger-2007-mre-Thesis.pdf) the solutions discussed (in sector *2.3.3 Existing Solutions*).